# How to use to Gram-Schmidt procedure with the inner product defined as $\langle p(x),q(x)\rangle = \int_{-1}^{1} p(x)q(x)\,dx?$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

This was a question on a practice exam (no solutions) that I could not figure out.

Question:

Consider the subspace spanned by ${x^3,x^4,x^5}$ in $P_{2019}$, the real vector space of polynomials of degree at most 2019. Define the integral inner product on $P_{2019}$ by:

$$\langle p(x),q(x)\rangle = \int_{-1}^{1} p(x)q(x)\,dx.$$

Use the Gram-Schmidt procedure to find an orthogonal basis for this subspace.

I am sure I am just missing something simple here, but how can you calculate the inner product as proposed in the question without having $q(x)$ defined?

Comment: your bounds are backwards

Comment: Yes they are, thanks for noticing that. Editing now.

Comment: Fortunately $q$ *is* defined, so there is no problem here.

Comment: https://www.math.tamu.edu/~yvorobet/MATH304-503/Lect4-04web.pdf see page 5

Comment: Without Gram-Schmidt: easily $x^4\bot x^3$ and $x^4\bot x^5$. You are left with finding a constant $a$ such that $x^3\bot x^5+ax^3$.

Comment: How can you calculate the standard Euclidean inner product on $\mathbb R^n$, $\langle v,w\rangle = \sum v_kw_k$, without having $w$ defined?

Comment: Gram-Schmidt can be written using only the operations of the inner product space; for example, to orthonormalize $w_1,w_2,w_3$ you take $v_1=w_1,u_1=v_1/\| v_1 \|$, $v_2=w_2-u_1 \langle u_1,w_2 \rangle,u_2=v_2/\| v_2 \|$, $v_3=w_3-u_1 \langle u_1,w_3 \rangle-u_2 \langle u_2,w_3 \rangle,u_3=v_3/\| v_3 \|$. What the inner product and associated norm are do not change this procedure, they only change how the computation of those inner products/norms have to be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You proceed as usual. Step 1: normalize $x^3:$
\begin{align*}
\left\|x^3\right\|^2=\left\langle x^3,x^3\right\rangle&=\int_{-1}^{1}x^3x^3\,dx \\
&=\int_{-1}^1x^6\,dx \\
&=\frac{x^7}{7}\bigg|_{-1}^1 \\
&=\frac27.
\end{align*}
Therefore, $\left\|x^3\right\|=\sqrt{2/7},$ and we divide the vector by its norm to obtain
$$e_1=\sqrt{\frac72}\,x^3.$$
Next, we perform the operation
\begin{align*}
 u_2&=x^4-e_1\left\langle x^4,e_1\right\rangle \\
&=x^4-\sqrt{\frac72}\,x^3\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{\frac72}\,x^3\,x^4\,dx \\
&=x^4-\frac72\,x^3\int_{-1}^1x^7\,dx \\
&=x^4-\frac72\,x^3\left(\frac{x^8}{8}\right)_{-1}^1 \\
&=x^4.
\end{align*}
Then you normalize $x^4$ as before to obtain $e_2,$ and continue. Can you finish?

Comment: Thank you! That helps a lot!

Comment: You're very welcome! Have a good one!